# Are there any current female saints in shaktism?

Tags: shaktism, saint

Are there any current saints in Shaktism,like Sarada Devi or like anandamayi maa were for general hinduism?

Are there any saints in shaktism right now that are well known?

Comment: yes, there are. tvaritambā of rajrajeshwari peeth, kādi, gujrat is one among them. many in south india are initiated into shri vidya by guhananda mandali of sri chidananda natha ji and many are doing their upasana at current times too